# How can I switch to iOS iPhone tabview2 with a button on tabview1

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller

I've read some internet posts that nearly answer my question, but I cannot put the pieces together.   I have a two-tab iPhone app, with the two associated view controllers, h, m, xibs et al.   There's a button on tabview1 by which I want to switch programmatically to tabview2.   I've read discussions about setting up a root view controller to manage this, but the examples just haven't carried enough detail for me to figure it out, and appear to suggest that I change over to a nav-based app, which I really don't want to do.  Anyone have the patience to explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the way I handled it was to have my AppDelegate (which owns the tabController) handle it.  So in the caller, I used:

```
[(AppDelegate_Shared *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] popToMainView];
```

and then in the appDelegate:

```
-(void)  popToMainView {
    UITabBarController * myTabBar = self.tabBarController;
    myTabBar.selectedIndex = 0;  //jump to first view.
    [[myTabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
         // this last line necessary iff you know firstView has a navcontroller and you want to be at the root
}
```

Comment: tx much mackworth.   Your selectedIndex set me thinking that there may be an even easier way.   In tabview1's button logic I just did that alone and voila, it changed views exactly as I wanted.  No delegate, no special function.

Comment: You're correct, although it means that tabView1 knows details about its parent (that it's a tabcontroller, which index is main etc), which really isn't very good structure.  Oh, and if that helped, feel free to mark the question answered!